# The requirement of a spiritual guide does not make sense

Tags: sufism, spirituality

Salamun Alaykum,

I will try to cut it short. Everywhere that I have looked, I have always seen people claiming that a spiritual journey always demands a spiritual guide or a teacher (shaikh). And without one, diving into inner dimensions of reality and experiencing the true love and being intoxicated by it is not possible, it is said. However, such a statement makes me so confused.

First of all, such spiritual guides are pretty impossible to find, especially in the age of modernity in which there are a lot of people claiming themselves as shaiks although a true shaikh would never claim himself as a shaikh and call people to him. So 'finding a shaikh' itself is paradoxical today.

Secondly, Allah, the Most Just and Merciful, would not turn down those that want to hop in this journey of Love to find Him, however, the idea of a strict requirement of a spiritual guide does not provide any equality in opportunity for those with iman.

What are your thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: "I have always seen people claiming that a spiritual journey always demands a spiritual guide or a teacher (shaikh)" - Does that accords with the Revelation?

Comment: As is written this question is off-topic as it is invitation for subjective answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that God will judge us based on our principles. The commen sense is our guide through modern problems (Homosexualty, Adultery...) The journey to high spirituality can be achieved only by yourself. Read coran more frequently (it has all the necessary spiritual guidance), and also don't forget about Hadith and the life of our prophet, which is really makes you aware of the things that you should avoid and of course the instructions into the level of Al-Yakin(certainty). Finally, mentioning ALLAH (Adikr) is also a way to climb faith levels. In consequence if you only follow this three advices, you won't need someone as a spiritual guide or a teacher (shaikh).
I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're right it doesn't make sense.

God has blessed us with wisdom. Why should we hand it to another?! There are lots of incidents where the Shaikhs abuse their powers. Followers give leaders power.

Having that said a person needs guidance. **Guidance doesn't mean obedience.** You get the guidance and then you process it and do what you got to do. You never cancel out your own intuition. Additionally knowledge is powerful asset to be able to differentiate between right and wrong. Seeking knowledge is recommended. If the Shaikh has knowledge then learn that, but again process it, the minute he puts himself above you, then he's exceeded his authority.

**Quran:**

> [Anbya: 7](https://quran.com/21/7)
>
> *فَاسْأَلُوا أَهْلَ الذِّكْرِ إِن كُنتُمْ لَا تَعْلَمُونَ*
>
> So ask the people of the message if you do not know.

**Hadith:**

> *هَلَكَ مَنْ لَیْسَ لَهُ حَكیمٌ یُرْشِدُهُ*
>
> one who doesn't have a wise person to guide him will perish

Obedience in Quran is only to Allah, the prophet and [those vested with authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_obedience_verse)

A Shaikh is never of them.